# cPanel - .htaccess point to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework2, subdomain, cpanel, document-root

I have 2 domains point to the same hosting.

**domain_a.com** & **domain_b.com**

The **domain_b.com** is actually point to subdomain of **domain_a.com** (i.e. domain_b.domain_a.com)

Directory structure

```
public_html
 |
 |---- domain_a
 |---- domain_b
 |---- ...
 |---- .htaccess
```

Content of `.htaccess` is

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain_a.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain_a/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain_a/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain_a.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain_a/index.html [L]
```

However, my **domain_b.com** actually is using ZendFramework 2. Which have the document root on `public` dir

i.e.

```
public_html
  |
  |---- domain_a
  |---- domain_b
          |---- public  <------ HERE
  |---- ...
  |---- .htaccess
```

At the end, I get this result

[image]

Any idea?

### Edit

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain_a\.com$
RewriteRule !^domain_a(/|$) /domain_a%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain_b\.com$
RewriteRule !^domain_b/public(/|$) /domain_b/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This cause the error `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

In `domain_b/public` also has a `.htaccess` file. This is default from [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/)

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What is the question? Show `VirtualHost` entries of both domains.

Comment: This is shared hosting, I don't think I can change the virtual host. Basically I want my `domain_b.com` point to `public_html/domain_b/public`

Comment: I don't want you to change I just want to see those entries to understand your setup.

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this by setting the path of subdomain to `domain_b/public/` during subdomain creation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain_a\.com$
RewriteRule !^domain_a(/|$) /domain_a%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain_b\.com$
RewriteRule !^domain_b/public/index\.php(/|$) /domain_b/public/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Now I get 500 Internal Server Error. I can't find the vhost config file.

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log for the reason of this 500

Comment: `[alert] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] /home/user/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: Well that means you make some typo while copy/pasting this answer. If you see above I am not even using any flag in `RewriteCond`. You need to make sure that there is no stray space in `RewriteCond` lines of your .htaccess.

Comment: Ya, you're right. Now I get this `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: `RewriteRule !^domain_a(/|$) /domain_a%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` the **domain_a** is folder name or domain name?

Comment: In this case it is a `folder name`.

Comment: Ya, but it get the error `Request exceed the limit of 10 internal ...`

Comment: Just these 2 rules cannot cause looping but you might have some other rules also. Can you post your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Updated on **Edit** section

Comment: Are there any `.htaccess` files inside `/domain_a/` OR `/domain_b/` directories?

Comment: Now no more error, but back to the original screen. i.e. `Index of / .....` Still cannot get access to `public` dir

Comment: Back to / for which URL? What happens when you enter: `http://domain_b.com/domain_b/public/index.php`?

Comment: It shows [this page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSWn0.png). `http://domain_b.com/domain_b/public/index.php` I get 500 server error

Comment: For 500 error you need to check Apache `error.log`. What if you try to open `http://domain_b.com/domain_b/public/`?

Comment: I get this `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` for both with & without `index.php`

Comment: Can you add this line `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 [OR]` just above `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]` in your `domain_b/public/.htaccess`?

Comment: Same result. If domain_b.com will get [this page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSWn0.png), whereas `http://domain_b.com/domain_b/public/` will get this `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Ok rename .htaccess in `DocumentRoot` to something else and try to open: `http://domain_b.com/domain_b/public/`

Comment: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` and got some php error. [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/) is designed not to point to the public folder directly.

Comment: Well that tells me there is an existing problem in your setup which is causing looping even without any `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`. You wrote ` Zend Framework 2 is designed not to point to the public folder directly` in that case how do you load default page of `domain_b.com` (assuming there is no .htaccess in DocumentRoot)

Comment: I mean zend Framework 2 is not accessible by the url with `/public/`, but in vhost should point to the `public` folder. I just try to re-upload the whole project and now I get `SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/username/public_html/domain_b" is writeable by group, referer: http://domain_b.com/` and `Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://domain_b.com/`

Comment: Change your permissions on that folder to 755

Comment: Now I renamed `.htaccess` in `domain_b/public/` to other name,when I access to http://domain_b.com/domain_b/public get this `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` If access to http://domain_b.com/public/ it redirect to login route but with `public/` prefix _(i.e. http://domain_b.com/public/account/login)_ and it suppose to be `http://domain_b.com/account/login for the login page